# How to pass arguments to UI in Electron, using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, electron

I am using Flask to create a webapp and want to create a desktop app for the same. Now in Flask, I can just pass a list along with the HTML file in render_template function

```
return render_template('index.html', someList = someList)
```

and then use it in HTML file as follows:

```
{% for i in someList %}
  #doSomething
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone tell me Electron equivalent for this?

Comment: You mean using a templating language? If that's it you can use React+Redux or some other front end framewok to create app's like you do with Python+Pug

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should use the electron application as a UI for your flask app. This would mean that you start the flask server using electron and then navigate to the url in the electron UI.
Here is an example of how to do this:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  //call python?
  var subpy = require('child_process').spawn('python', ['./hello.py']);

  var rq = require('request-promise');
  var mainAddr = 'http://localhost:5000';

  var openWindow = function(){
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600});
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    // mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
    mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:5000');
    // Open the devtools.
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
      // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
      // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
      // when you should delete the corresponding element.
      mainWindow = null;
      // kill python
      subpy.kill('SIGINT');
    });
  };
```

The full project can be found on github:
https://github.com/fyears/electron-python-example